# Выбрать первые 3 созданные экземпляра класса JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет!
Возникла задача:
Существует n кол-во дивов с одним классом и надо выбрать именно первые 3 div с помощью JS или JQ. Никак не могу найти правильный селектор..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если речь о селекторах, то используйте `:lt()`

```
$(".sample:lt(3)")...
```

но также к примеру можете использовать и методы фильтрации:

```
$(".sample").slice(0,2)
```

Comment: Интересно, а с querySelector не работает...

Comment: спасибо! я оказываться уже юзал этот селектор, но не правильно писал синтаксически его...но это помогло!

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME это расширенный селектор jq